Error in laravel component ; Undefined variable $acceptIcon
I use Laravel 11 and my component work perfectly in local, but I have error in production
component class:
<?php

namespace App\View\Components\dashboard\cafe;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Illuminate\View\Component;

class VerifyButtons extends Component
{
    public string $acceptIcon;
    public string $rejectIcon;

    public function __construct(public $status, public string $propertyName)
    {
        $this->acceptIcon = asset('assets/images/default-accept.svg');
        $this->rejectIcon = asset('assets/images/default-reject.svg');
        if ($this->status)
            $this->acceptIcon = asset('assets/images/accept.svg');

        if ($this->status === 0)
            $this->rejectIcon = asset('assets/images/reject.svg');
    }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     */
    public function render(): View|Closure|string
    {
        return view('components.dashboard.cafe.verify-buttons');
    }
}


and in blade:
<div class="flex gap-3">
    <img class="w-[28px] cursor-pointer" wire:click="$set('{{$propertyName}}',1)"
         src="{{$acceptIcon}}"/>
    <img class="w-[28px] cursor-pointer" wire:click="$set('{{$propertyName}}',0)"
         src="{{$rejectIcon}}"/>
</div>


Php verison in local and production is 8.3.14
error:
Undefined variable $acceptIcon


Can you please share the full log message?

have you tried to clear your cache (view/config...) in production ?
